# Injecting EJB with @EJB or @Inject in the service layer for my REST web service?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have created some EJB's, they are annotated with `@Stateless`. To use these EJB's in the other EJB's I am currently using the `@EJB`annotation. I have created another layer (over the service layer) for my REST web service (I am using JAX-RS) and I wonder if I should use `@EJB` or `@Inject`. I know these two are different things - and they probably live in different containers? If I use `@Inject` do I get the same EJB that I would have gotten with `@EJB`. Or do I get an EJB from the CDI container?

I also guess that by using `@Inject` I don't get all the EJB features that I would have gotten from `@EJB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Inject` supports the injection of EJBs.  There is no functional difference, CDI is doing a lookup to find the object using the standard JNDI locations.  The `@EJB` annotation has some additional capabilities, mostly around remoting or non standard JNDI locations that wouldn't be supported OOTB by `@Inject`

Answer (score 0):

Intersting link about: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html I didn't try by myself, but looks like @Inject more powerful than @EJB...